# "locate" process in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, system

Frequently I have seen in the System Monitor a process called "locate", running once a day or more. It consumes a lot a CPU and I do not understand if it is useful or not. Can I configure it to run less times per week? Where could I find more information about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process 'locate' is a find utility to help you locate certain commands, files, documents, etc. It is useful wherein someone needs to locate a particular file or command on the system. Is this a multi-user system? If so, someone is probably using it to locate what they need.

The updatedb command performs the locate update, so using "locate" just means that it is in use on the system. you could try to restrict access to the command if it is a real bother. To learn more try:

```
man locate
```

which will provide the full manual page details.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is a multi-user system, so I have decided to restrict it more.